# How do I subscribe to channel updates using Telegram API?

Tags: api, telegram

I'm finding the Telegram API docs a little hard to follow.

Does anyone know if there is a way to programmatically subscribe to updates from a specific channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You must create a bot and add bot to channel 
Then, by using the api telegram, tell your robot to send the post to the telegram